# Why can't my code correctly output 'C' information in the VS Code environment, but it works with GCC? It might be due to issues related to bitfields

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bit-fields

[false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bi2Gu.png)
[true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIIp.png)

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
enum Leve{Freshman,Sophomore,Junior,Senior};
enum Grade{A,B,C,D};
class student {
public:
    student(unsigned number, Leve leve, Grade grade):number(number),leve(leve),grade(grade){};
    void show();
private:
    unsigned number : 27;
    Leve leve:2;
    Grade grade:2;
};
void student::show() {
    cout << "number:" << number <<"\tLeve:";
    switch (leve) {
        case Freshman:cout << "Freshman";
            break;
        case Sophomore:cout << "Sophomore";
            break;
        case 2:cout << "Junior" ;

            break;
        case 3:cout << "Senior";

    }
    cout << "\tGrade:";
    switch (grade) {
        case 0:cout << "A";
            break;
        case 1:cout << "B";
            break;
        case 2:cout << "C";
            break;
        case 3:cout << "D";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
    student a(4536978, Sophomore, A);
    student b(54324783, Freshman, C);
    student c(58953611, Junior, D);
    cout << "The size of student is " << sizeof(a)<<endl;
    a.show();
    b.show();
    c.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Why can't my code correctly output 'C' information in the VS Code environment, but it works with GCC? It might be due to issues related to bitfields.
Having done some research, it might be related to the bitfield padding mechanism, but I don't understand why.

Comment: VSCode requires an external compiler. Which one are you using? Can you explain in more detail what the issue is?

Comment: There are two images before the code, and after compiling with Microsoft Visual C++, it can't display the result for 'C', but it works with GCC.

Comment: Of course Microsoft Visual C++ doesn't work, given all the warning the compiler is generating.  If you fix those warnings, does it work then?

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is my first time trying to ask for help on the internet, and I'm very grateful. I will remember your assistance! Actually, this is my friend's issue; I don't have VS Code because I use CLion, but I'll download and try it out soon!"

Comment: If you are asking about Visual Studio and not VS Code you should edit your question to make that clear. I didn't look at the images. You should be able to explain the problem without them in most cases.

Comment: This is indeed a compiler issue. GCC produces the expected result, but in the VS compiler, the information for 'C' is missing. You can take a look at the images, which are the two hyperlinks for 'true' and 'false'.

Comment: seems to not like having bitfields with mixed types, if you change the type of the enums to `unsigned` it works

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail? I changed all the 'case' labels in the first 'switch' statement to integers, but it still doesn't run in the VS environment.

Comment: If you step through with the Visual Studio debugger, you'll see that when `grade` is `-1`, that case is not handled anywhere.  I'd fix the problem with `enum Grade:unsigned{A,B,C,D};` and pay attention to compiler warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the type of an `enum` in MSVC is `int` GCC seems to default to an unsigned type (the default underlying type for an enum isn't set by the standard). As you've only assigned 2 bits to each field the range of storable values is `-2` to `1`. If you explicitly set the underlying type of the enum to an unsigned type then 2 bits will be sufficient to store your 4 values.

```
enum Leve:uint8_t { Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior };
enum Grade:uint8_t { A, B, C, D };
```

Comment: You're an absolute genius, thank you so much! My computer time for today is about to end, and I have to leave the computer lab. I truly appreciate your help in the final moments!

Comment: Pulled ye-old rabbit out of the hat at the critical moment.  Makes perfect sense for bit operations where sign-extension may be an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Wishing you a happy life!I've understood this issue; it's caused by the different implementations of MSVC and GCC. The following text is what I sent to my friend

After attempting to standardize the underlying type as 'int,' both MSVC and GCC produce output results of -2 and -1. The intuition is that the sign bit is being interpreted. According to the GCC 13.20 documentation, specifically in '4.9 Structures, Unions, Enumerations, and Bit-Fields'

Comment: (page 533 [Figure 4]), it states, 'Normally, the type is unsigned int if there are no negative values in the enumeration, otherwise int.' This makes the conclusion quite clear: when mixing enumeration types, GCC's default underlying type is unsigned integer, which is why the issue cannot be reproduced in the GCC environment. However, in MSVC's implementation,

Comment: the default underlying type for 'enum' is 'int' (Microsoft's documentation does not mention the implementation, and its wording is problematic [Figure 5]). You have specified a width of 2 bits, and the first bit is being interpreted as the sign bit. This is why MSVC results in issues, and if it were standardized as 'int,' GCC would also yield -2 and -1.